# VsCode checkout removed all of the new files

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have been working on this project for almost 6 months.
Long story short, I have not updated the git repository in the last 3 months
Today I decided that, just in case anything goes wrong, I wanted to commit my changes and push them.

Using the VS Code Git source control I committed all of the changes that I made.
After committing, I tried to push to the GitHub repo and it said
`Please check out a branch to push to a remote`.

So I pressed the `checkout to` button and it removed all my work. Now it only shows 3 months old project files.

Is there any way I could go back to the previous file? Git log does not show the new commit in both branches.

Comment: You said that you _committed_ the changes. Does `git reflog` show your commit?

Comment: @fluffy yes it does

Comment: This is why it may not appear in the git log (anonymous commit as now to a part of any ref history). Then it sounds easy and no worries: you can _temporarily_ tag that commit to prevent branch moving and garbage collection in git (otherwise it would get lost). This is your check point you can do the rest from. The rest (merge, rebase, cherry-picking, etc) depends on the rules established in your project.

Comment: Thanks @fluffy can you provide me an example or steps so that I don't mess up this commit ? there are no rules for this project as its personal one and I am the only one working on it. just anything that would get me back to that commit in any branch would be appreciated.

Comment: First off, tag the commit from the reflog to make sure it won't get lost (`git tag <CHECKPOINT_NAME> <COMMIT_ID>`). Then switch to your upstream branch (that one with old commits; you're probably there right now or do `git checkout <BRANCH_NAME>`) and then merge the tag to this branch (`git merge <CHECKPOINT_NAME>`) -- the history won't be linear, but just check whether it works.

Comment: @fluffy Thanks you are a hero <3